# Improper usage of new with inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, allocation

I am trying to figure out a crash, and have boiled it down the following sample:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual unsigned int    GetNum  () = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base
{
    int data;   // <--- commmenting this out removes the crash

public:
    Derived() {}
    virtual unsigned int    GetNum() { return 1; }
};

void func() {

    Base** ppBases;

    unsigned int xLen = 3;
    unsigned int yLen = 4;

    ppBases = new Base*[xLen];
    for(unsigned int x = 0; x < xLen; ++x) {
        ppBases[x] = new Derived[yLen];
        for(unsigned int y = 0; y < yLen; ++y) {
            Base* curBase = dynamic_cast<Base*>(&(ppBases[x][y]));
            Derived* curDerived = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(&(ppBases[x][y])); // <--- crashes with a null dereference
            unsigned int result = curBase->GetNum();
            result = result;
        }
    }
}
```

I guessed that Derived isn't actually being allocated with the proper size. Changing ppBases to be a tripple pointer (like so) makes everything work:

```
void func() {

    Base*** ppBases;

    unsigned int xLen = 3;
    unsigned int yLen = 4;

    ppBases = new Base**[xLen];
    for(unsigned int x = 0; x < xLen; ++x) {
        ppBases[x] = new Base*[yLen];
        for(unsigned int y = 0; y < yLen; ++y) {
            ppBases[x][y] = new Derived();
            Base* curBase = dynamic_cast<Base*>(ppBases[x][y]);
            Derived* curDerived = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(ppBases[x][y]);
            unsigned int result = curBase->GetNum();
            result = result;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand why though.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
 ppBases[x] = new Derived[yLen];
```

You're assigning an array of `Derived` objects to a `Base *` pointer.  So when you write  `ppBases[x][y]` the compiler works with the type of the pointer, which is `Base *`, and index appropriately.  So `ppBases[x][1]` does not refer to the second `Derived` object in the allocated array.

Comment: C++ uses the size of the data type to determine the amount of memory required to allocate the array.  Because they are essentially the same size (once you comment out int data), this is why it works at that point.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see now. Thanks for the clear explanations :)